# On highest degree of precision of numerical integration scheme that comes from interpolating polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, numerical-calculus

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be distinct points in $[a,b]$ and $l_i(x):=\prod_{k\ne i}\dfrac {x-x_k}{x_i-x_k} $.  Let $w_i=\int_a^b l_i(x)dx$. For every $f \in C[a,b]$, let $I_n(f):=\sum_{i=1}^n w_i f(x_i)$.

If $I_n(P)=\int_a^b P(t) dt$ for every polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $\le m$, then how to prove that $m \le 2n-1$ ?

(Please do not quote any big theorems, I am trying to prove that any numerical intergation formula that comes from interpolation at $n$-points, has degree of precision  at most $2n-1$)

Comment: Do you already know anything about Gaussian quadrature?

Comment: @Ian: yes I know Gaussian quadrature and I know that it has degree of precision $2n-1$ ... now I am trying to prove that it is the best we can do  ...

Comment: One way to do it is very similar to how you prove Gaussian quadrature has positive weights: construct a polynomial of degree $2n$ which is everywhere nonnegative and which vanishes at all $n$ nodes. There's a somewhat obvious way to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=(x-x_1)^2(x-x_2)^2\cdots (x-x_n)^2$.

This $f$ is nonnegative everywhere and positive at all but finitely many points, so its integral over any nontrivial interval is positive. On the other hand, any integration rule based on the values at the $n$ points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ must return zero, so it can't integrate $f$ exactly. That's a polynomial of degree $2n$, and thus no linear combination of values at $n$ points can find the integral accurately for all polynomials of degree up to $2n$.